# Parenthesis error in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have used following query in my Oracle DB:

```
UPDATE test5_rdf_memoization 
SET object ='galib' 
WHERE ( predicate='platform' AND 
    object IS NULL AND 
    subject IN ( SELECT subject 
                FROM test5_rdf_memoization t1, 
                    test_parameters_new_5 t2, 
                    test_parameter_detail t3 
                WHERE (t1.object = t2.id AND 
                    t2.id = t3.parameter AND 
                    t1.predicate = 'parameter' AND 
                    t3.host_tool_detail = 1 AND 
                    (t1.subject >= 624))  
                order by t1.subject) );
```

but it is giving me following  error

```
 Error starting at line 1 in command: 
    UPDATE test5_rdf_memoization SET
     object ='galib' WHERE ( predicate='platform' AND object IS NULL AND
     subject IN ( SELECT subject FROM test5_rdf_memoization t1,
     test_parameters_new_5 t2, test_parameter_detail t3 WHERE (t1.object =
     t2.id AND t2.id = t3.parameter AND t1.predicate = 'parameter' AND
     t3.host_tool_detail = 1 AND (t1.subject >= 624))  order by t1.subject)
     ) 
 Error at Command Line:2 Column:10 Error report: SQL Error:
 ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

I have tried with different combinations of parenthesis but it is not working. Could any one please help me with this?

Comment: An `order by` in a sub-select doesn't make any sense. It's totally useless and probably the cause for your error.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle often throws `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` to indicate a syntax error, usually because it has found an illegal clause before it found a matching bracket.

In this case it is objecting to the `ORDER BY` clause.  We cannot order such sub-queries.  Indeed sorting doesn't matter because the statement is merely testing for the *existence* of a record, so who cares whether we find the record randomly first or sorted into alphanumeric third?  Well, obviously sorting burns CPU cycles so unnecessary sorting is bad from a performance perspective but it doesn't change the outcome.

> "I need data sorted by subject."

No you don't.  You're updating all the records in  `test5_rdf_memoization` which match a specific set of criteria to the same value.   So again, the order in which they are updated doesn't matter, because the outcome is the same.

---

If you're not happy with this explanation please edit your question to explain your business requirement so we can provide a solution which will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -- I only see a need for a single set of parentheses around your `IN` statement.  I also removed the `ORDER BY` statement:

```
UPDATE test5_rdf_memoization 
SET object ='galib' 
WHERE predicate='platform' 
   AND object IS NULL 
   AND subject IN ( 
       SELECT subject 
       FROM test5_rdf_memoization t1, 
            test_parameters_new_5 t2, 
            test_parameter_detail t3 
       WHERE t1.object = t2.id 
            AND t2.id = t3.parameter 
            AND t1.predicate = 'parameter' 
            AND t3.host_tool_detail = 1 
            AND t1.subject >= 624)
```

I prefer using `INNER JOINs` though:

```
UPDATE test5_rdf_memoization 
SET object ='galib' 
WHERE predicate='platform' 
   AND object IS NULL 
   AND subject IN ( 
       SELECT subject 
       FROM test5_rdf_memoization t1 
           INNER JOIN test_parameters_new_5 t2 
               ON t1.object = t2.id 
           INNER JOIN test_parameter_detail t3 
               ON t2.id = t3.parameter 
       WHERE t1.predicate = 'parameter' 
            AND t3.host_tool_detail = 1 
            AND t1.subject >= 624)
```

Comment: I need data sorted by subject. If I remove order by then data is not sorted. If you have any idea then please let me know.

Comment: @user2151087: you are **updating** the data. Sorting does not make any sense in that context.